# react native render push notification android

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I'm using react-native-push-notification libary for push notification to android.
I get the notification from my server with GCM.
I got the function 'onNotification' works, and when I console it I see the message notification in the console.
How can I render the notification and display every notification to the user including button? I tried to save the recived notification by state or call functions, but it doesn't work it's seems doesnt know the external functions.

here is the code-

```js
 componentDidMount(){
        PushNotification.configure({

            onNotification: function(notification) {
                console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
            },
           
            senderID: "********",
            popInitialNotification: true,


        });
    }



render() {
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>Notification</Text>
                </View>

            );

        }

}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Android, I will recommend using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). Also, the package react-native-push-notification is difficult to configure and use for Android. I will recommend using react-native-firebase instead.

I have published a tutorial on how to do it using [FCM and react-native-firebase](https://vijayt.com/post/remote-push-notifications-in-react-native-android-app/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want button in notification and on click on that button run the specific function then you should try

[react-native-notifications](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications)

It allows you to provide additional functionality to your users outside of your application such as action buttons.

[image]